# How to boost Entity Framework Unit Of Work Performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, entity-framework

Please see the following situation:

I do have a CSV files of which I import a couple of fields (not all in SQL server using Entity Framework with the Unit Of Work and Repository Design Pattern).

```
var newGenericArticle = new GenericArticle
{
    GlnCode = data[2],
    Description = data[5],
    VendorId = data[4],
    ItemNumber = data[1],
    ItemUOM = data[3],
    VendorName = data[12]
};

var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new AppServerContext());
unitOfWork.GenericArticlesRepository.Insert(newGenericArticle);

unitOfWork.Commit();
```

Now, the only way to uniquely identify a record, is checking on 4 fields: `GlnCode`, `Description`, `VendorID` and `Item Number`.

So, before I can insert a record, I need to check whether or not is exists:

```
 var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new AppServerContext());

 // If the article is already existing, update the vendor name.
 if (unitOfWork.GenericArticlesRepository.GetAllByFilter(
         x => x.GlnCode.Equals(newGenericArticle.GlnCode) &&
              x.Description.Equals(newGenericArticle.Description) &&
              x.VendorId.Equals(newGenericArticle.VendorId) &&
              x.ItemNumber.Equals(newGenericArticle.ItemNumber)).Any())
 {
     var foundArticle = unitOfWork.GenericArticlesRepository.GetByFilter(
         x => x.GlnCode.Equals(newGenericArticle.GlnCode) &&
              x.Description.Equals(newGenericArticle.Description) &&
              x.VendorId.Equals(newGenericArticle.VendorId) &&
              x.ItemNumber.Equals(newGenericArticle.ItemNumber));

     foundArticle.VendorName = newGenericArticle.VendorName;

     unitOfWork.GenericArticlesRepository.Update(foundArticle);
 }
```

If it's existing, I need to update it, which you see in the code above.

Now, you need to know that I'm importing around 1.500.000 records, so quite a lot.
And it's the filter which causes the CPU to reach almost 100%.

The `GetAllByFilter' method is quite simple and does the following:

```
return !Entities.Any() ? null : !Entities.Where(predicate).Any() ? null : Entities.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
```

Where `predicate` equals `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`

Is there anything that I can do to make sure that the server's CPU doesn't reach 100%?

Note: I'm using SQL Server 2012

Kind regards

Comment: I would suggest to [use a stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17274826/806975), or try a [bulk insert extension](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Why are you so `.Any()` happy?  You are literally querying the database 10 times for every insert.  Now, granted, that Any tends to use an EXISTS query, but it's still a query.  In particular, you call Entities.Any(), then Any on the predicate, then return an iqueryable and then call Any on that again!  Sheesh.

Comment: But beyond that, EF is just not designed for this.. It's not a batch or bulk job processor... Use SqlBulkCopy class instead.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Any suggestion on how to get rid of the `Any()` implementation to make it more performant?

Comment: Yes, just do a single query with a where clause and your four conditions with a SingleOrDefault (assuming it can only return a single record), and if it's null it means it doesn't exist, so skip the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found another solution which wasn't proposed here, so I'll be answering my own question.

I will have a temp table in which I will import all the data, and after the import, I'll execute a stored procedure which will execute a `Merge` command to populate the destinatio table. I do believe that this is the most performant.

Answer (score 2):

Wrong tool for the task. You should never process a million+ records one at at time. Insert the records to a staging table using bulk insert and clean (if need be) and then use a stored proc to do the processing in a set-based way or use the tool designed for this, SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you indexed on those four fields in your database?  That is the first thing that I would do.

Ok, I would recommend trying the following:
[Improving bulk insert performance in Entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107206/improving-bulk-insert-performance-in-entity-framework?lq=1)

To summarize,
Do not call SaveChanges() after every insert or update.  Instead, call every 1-2k records so that the inserts/updates are made in batches to the database.

Also, optionally change the following parameters on your context:

```
yourContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
yourContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Not done it yet. Will do right away. Didn't understand on how I missed that. Any other ideas that you have?

Comment: The fields are index right now, but the problem remains the same. I do have a table that has 4 keys (the 4 columns that makes a record unique). After that, I've created an index for those 4 keys, but the problem still remains.

Comment: In that case you might want to use a stored procedure with a MERGE statement.  You can call stored procedures from entity framework

Comment: I will give that a try, but is that such a performance boost as I still need to execute the SP for every record in the file to import. Meaning, 1.500.000 calls to the Stored Procedure?

Comment: No, you can use a table value parameter and send it in batches. https://mikesdotnet.wordpress.com/2013/03/17/inserting-data-into-a-sql-server-database-using-a-table-valued-parameter/

Comment: Better link for EF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157345/entity-framework-stored-procedure-table-value-parameter

Comment: Ok, I'm a bit lost here. What's the first approach that I should try? Using a Stored Procedure with the MERGE command and executing one by one. Or use a table value parameter and send it in batches? Or does those 2 goes along and can't the first be used without the second?

Comment: You can send your data in a table parameter and use the merge command on that data to either insert or update.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you can use this method as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107206/improving-bulk-insert-performance-in-entity-framework?lq=1

Comment: Now I see it, and never do a delete, so records will never be removed. Any idea on how to accomplish the same is some records might be removed?

Comment: I've accepted your answer already, but I do hope that you can point me out on how to work with table parameters and the merge command in combination with deletion of data.